# Multiprocessing queue python-daemon

Tags: python, python-daemon, start-stop-daemon

I need linux daemon on python with multiprocessing queue.

I allready trying python demonize but it's have an issue with pid's,access rights and start/stop funcs.

This is opion through python-daemon package.

Programm listing:

```
#file test_daemon.py   
# To kick off the script, run the following from the python directory:
#   PYTHONPATH=`pwd` python testdaemon.py start    
#standard python libs
import logging
import multiprocessing
import random
import time
q = multiprocessing.Queue()

#third party libs
from daemon import runner

def printt(q):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(q.get())

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/var/run/testdaemon/testdaemon.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5

    def run(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=printt, args=(q, ))
        p.start()

        while True:
            if q.empty():
                q.put(random.sample(range(1, 100), 5))
                print('put queue')
                time.sleep(0.05)
```

error:

```
File "test_daemon.py", line 49, in <module>
    daemon_runner.do_action()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/runner.py", line 274, in do_action
    func(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/runner.py", line 193, in _start
    self.app.run()
  File "test_daemon.py", line 32, in run
    if q.empty():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 146, in empty
    return not self._poll()
IOError: poll() gave POLLNVAL or POLLERR
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test_daemon.py", line 17, in printt
    print(q.get())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv()
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '='.
```

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code looks fine..... how are you running it and what is happening in the `runner` object?

Comment: Modify your code by adding `global q` into each function. This is required because `queue` methods modifies the `queue` instance.